# What are the potential challenges of using VBA Driven excel workbooks that are networked together?

Tags: excel, networking, vba

I am currently working as a painter and now have an opportunity to build a company wide computer program for my current employer. There are about 30 people currently working for this company.

It will track actual hours worked vs. what was quoted, who is currently working on what job, etc. There will be about 7 stand alone computers in each of our separate shops connected with wifi to the server.

My main concern is I have never built a program with multiple excel workbooks that will share information. My plan for the system is as follows

I will design one workbook for shop use , another for office use, and finally 
one that will serve as data storage that the office and shop workbooks will pull and add data to. I will have about 7 copies of the shop workbook and about 4 of the office work distributed that will use the one storage workbook. This will all be done in VBA, I will not be using any sheet functions. There is already stuff in excel sheets so I figured this would be practical to still use except with userforms and vba.

If possible I am looking for feedback on any potential pit falls that my current plan may have. I am a self taught programmer that knows python and vba for excel. I just want some advice on my first big break in the programming world.

Comment: Don't do this, seriously.  Excel is not an RDMS.  If you have to use Excel, use it ***only*** as a front-end or reporting tool.  You'll save yourself endless aggravation if you use SQL Server, MySQL, or some other real backend - heck even Access would be better.

Comment: I am wanting learn mysql so this may be a good time to start. So I think if I understand you use mysql to hold all the data make the different relationships as needed and then possibly use excel as the interface? because for me VBA userform are SO MUCH EASIER THAN ANY THING FOR PYTHON as far as I know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I learned some basic Python in the past few years, but honestly I'm not a big fan of this.  I just don't like snakes!!  I'd recommend a web-based interface and SQL Server back-end.  Dispense with Excel all-together.  People tend to use Excel when they don't know what else to use, but this will inevitably lead to all kinds of technical issues, file corruption, etc.  Check out the links below for a great way of how to get started managing the kind of project you described in your OP.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/inserting-new-row-in-gridview-in-Asp-Net-2-0/

http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/2009/05/gridview-sqldatasource-insert-edit.html

https://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/data-access/introduction/creating-a-data-access-layer-cs

It's going to take a bit more work to get things setup and running initially, but you will be infinitely better off in the long run.  Finally, ASP.NET, with C# or VB.NET, as well as SQL Server Express, are all 100% completely free.